# Option Lighting in the Show function does not work

Tags: graphics3d, bugs, options, lighting

**Bug introduced in 11.2 or earlier and persisting through 13.0**

---

There are something wrong when I try to evaluate the example from `Lighting` Docs, here is the code:

```
lights = {{"Spot", Red, {{3, 3, 5}, {3, 3, 0}}, Pi/8}, {"Spot", Green, {{7, 3, 5}, {7, 3, 0}}, Pi/8}, {"Spot", Blue, {{5, 6, 5}, {5, 6, 0}}, Pi/8}}; 

plane = ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, -2}, {u, 0, 10}, {v, 0, 9}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> None, Axes -> False];  

Show[plane, Lighting -> lights]
```

Unfortunately, it does not work as expected in *Mathematica* version 11.3:

> [image: output]

But if we directly use the form

```
ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, -2}, {u, 0, 10}, {v, 0, 9}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> None, Axes -> False,Lighting -> lights]
```

it works:

> [image: output]

So I want to know the reason for creating the different outcomes, maybe researching the `InputForm` of output seems a feasible point, but I failed. Thanks for any info on this matter.

Comment: Same behavior in _v11.2_. Works as expected in _v9.0.1_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:** This is yet another case of automatic `PlotTheme` settings injecting directives that override the user-specified ones. So, a much easier fix is to add the option `PlotTheme -> None` to `ParametricPlot3D`.

```
plane = ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, -2}, {u, 0, 10}, {v, 0, 9}, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, 
   PlotTheme -> None];

Show[plane, Lighting -> lights]
```

[image]

**Note:** You can find a number of other issues fixed by explicitly removing `PlotTheme` on [this page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=PlotTheme++None).

**Original answer:**

I think this is a bug.

A fix is to remove `Lighting` from `plane` before using it in `Show`:

```
plane = ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, -2}, {u, 0, 10}, {v, 0, 9}, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 300];
planeb = DeleteCases[plane, Lighting -> _, All];
Grid[Labeled[ToExpression@#, #, Top] & /@ # & /@ 
 {{"plane", "Show[plane,Lighting->lights]"},
  {"planeb", "Show[planeb,Lighting->lights]"}}]
```

[image]

**What I think is happening:**

The lighting settings from the default `PlotTheme -> Automatic` are embedded as directives before graphics primitives in `ParametricPlot3D`. This can be verified using

```
Cases[plane, {a : ___, l : (Lighting -> _), ___} :> {a, l}, All]
```

[image]

or using

```
Cases["DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. 
  Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, ParametricPlot3D]), HoldPattern[Lighting -> _], All]
```

[image]

As noted by xzczd in comments, this issue does not arise in version 9:

```
Labeled[Row[Labeled[ToExpression@#, #, Top] & /@ {"plane", 
    "Show[plane,Lighting -> lights]"}], "Version: " <> $Version]
```

[image]