# Extracting Lighting specs used in a Graphics3D object

Tags: graphics3d, options, rendering, default, lighting

I'm getting a plot which is mostly fine with `Lighting->Automatic`, but a bit too dark. How do I go about getting the Lighting specification used in the plot so I could make it explicit and tweak it?

IE, need a utility which extracts lighting and related specs from a Graphics3D object.

```
f1[x_, y_] = 
  x (3/16 (9 - Sqrt[17]) x + 1/8 (9 - Sqrt[17]) y) + 
   y (1/8 (9 - Sqrt[17]) x + 3/4 (9 - Sqrt[17]) y);
f2[x_, y_] = 2 x^2 + 4 y^2;
Plot3D[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Cases[plot, HoldPattern[Lighting -> _], All]`?

Comment: Use ``SetSystemOptions["VisualizationOptions" -> {"Verbose" -> True}]`` before plotting, then search for ``Lightning`` in the output: ``Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[0.19699838300000003, 0.252204821, 0.33320940200000004]},   {"Directional", RGBColor[0.15473514000000002, 0.21284718000000002, 0.29811516000000005], ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[0.15473514000000002, 0.21284718000000002, 0.29811516000000005], ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[0.15473514000000002, 0.21284718000000002, 0.29811516000000005], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}``.

Comment: @Domen that doesn't fully reproduce the graph above...I guess there are some extra options I need besides Lighting?

Comment: You are correct. To reproduce the original plot, setting the ``Lighting`` is not enough, you also have to include the option ``PlotStyle``, which can also be found in the verbose output.

Comment: `Cases[plot, {d__, _GraphicsGroup} :> {d}, All]` to get the directives (including `Lighting`) used for each surface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to [this bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/191683/280), setting `Lighting` for `Graphics3D` as an option directly (e.g. via `Show`) doesn't work, and we must specify it individually for every object (or a group of objects) on the scene like a usual graphics directive. Starting at least from *Mathematica* 10 the built-in 3D plotting functions like `Plot3D` take the `Lighting` specifications from the absolute/resolved value of the `PlotStyle` option (which they generate from your input), and then build them into the list of graphics primitives (the first argument of `Graphics3D`). One can turn on verbose logging for this process by setting the system option `"VisualizationOptions" -> {"Verbose" -> True}`.

We [can](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172149/280) obtain the default styles with `Lighting` specifications included, as the value of `"DefaultPlotStyle"` suboption of `Method` option, via `` Charting`ResolvePlotTheme ``:

```
defaultplotstyle = "DefaultPlotStyle" /. 
   (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[$PlotTheme, Plot3D])
```

[image: screenshot]

We can obtain the actual (absolute) value of `PlotStyle` (generated by `Plot3D` for your particular input) from the output generated during evaluation of `Plot3D` after setting the system option `"VisualizationOptions" -> {"Verbose" -> True}` as [Domen](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/75628/domen) recommends in the comments. The code below automatizes this:

```
f1[x_, y_] = x (3/16 (9 - Sqrt[17]) x + 1/8 (9 - Sqrt[17]) y) + 
             y (1/8 (9 - Sqrt[17]) x + 3/4 (9 - Sqrt[17]) y);
f2[x_, y_] = 2 x^2 + 4 y^2;

Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  SetSystemOptions["VisualizationOptions" -> {"Verbose" -> True}],
  reap = Reap[Block[{Print = (Sow[{##}] &)},
      Plot3D[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
       BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]]];,
  SetSystemOptions["VisualizationOptions" -> {"Verbose" -> False}] 
  ];

Cases[reap, HoldPattern[PlotStyle -> _], {1, Infinity}] /. x_Real :> Round[x, .01]
```

> ```
> {PlotStyle -> {Directive[Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 3], RGBColor[0.88, 0.61, 0.14], 
>     Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[0.3, 0.22, 0.09]},
>        {"Directional", RGBColor[0.26, 0.18, 0.04], ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}, 
>        {"Directional", RGBColor[0.26, 0.18, 0.04], ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, 
>        {"Directional", RGBColor[0.26, 0.18, 0.04], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}], 
>    Directive[Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 3], RGBColor[0.37, 0.51, 0.71],
>      Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[0.2, 0.25, 0.33]}, 
>        {"Directional", RGBColor[0.15, 0.21, 0.3], ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}, 
>        {"Directional", RGBColor[0.15, 0.21, 0.3], ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, 
>        {"Directional", RGBColor[0.15, 0.21, 0.3], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}]}}
> ```

Having this, you can play with the directives to get the lighting you wish.